# Transmitting events from a Winform to another in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

How can I click a Button(to generate a color) in one form and change text color in a RichTextBox in a another form? Thanks in advance. (Newbie trying to understand C#)
Some code:

1.WinForm

```
 public delegate void ColorWindowEvent(Object sender, SecondrWindowEventArgs e);

    public partial class ColorWindow : Form
    {
        public event ColorWindowEvent myEventHandler;

        public ColorWindow ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void MyEvent(Object sender, ColorWindowEventArgs e)
        {
            string s = "";
            myEventHandler(this, new SecondWindowEventArgs(s)); 
        }

        private void btnRed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Color c = Color.Red;
            string s = c.ToString();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnBlue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Color c = Color.Blue;
            string str = c.ToString();
            this.Close();

        }

        private void btnGreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Color c = Color.Green;
            string s = c.ToString();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
    public class SecondWindowEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private string s;
        public SecondWindowEventArgs(string _s)
        {
            s = _s;

        }
        #region
        public string S
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

2.WinForm

```
public delegate void SecondWindowEvent(Object sender, FirstWindowEventArgs e);

public partial class SecondWindow : Form
{
    public event SecondWindowEvent myEventHandler;
    private string s;

    public SecondWindow(String _s)
    {
        s = _s;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void MyEvent(Object sender, FirstWindowEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = rtf2.Text;
        if (str != null)
        {
            myEventHandler(this, new FirstWindowEventArgs(str));
        }
    }
    private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void rtf2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myEventHandler != null)
        {
         myEventHandler(this, new FirstWindowEventArgs(rtf2.Text.Substring(rtf2.Text.Length - 1)));
         rtf2.ForeColor = Color.FromName(e.ToString());

        }
    }

    private void btnClearText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtf2.Text = " ";
    }

    private void rtf2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            FargeVindu fargeVindu = new FargeVindu();
            fargeVindu.minEventHandler += new FargeVinduEvent(fargeVindu_minEventHandler);
            fargeVindu.Show();
        }
        else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Delete)
        {

        }

    }
    protected void ColorWindow_myEventHandler(object sender, SecondWindowEventArgs e)
    {
        rtf2.ForeColor = Color.FromName(s);
    }

    Random random = new Random();
    private void SecondWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblText.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(255),
    random.Next(255), random.Next(255));
    }
    public Color getColor
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

3.WinForm

```
 public partial class FirstWindow : Form
    {
        public FirstWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = " ";
            SecondWindow secondWindow = new SecondWindow (str);

            secondWindow.myEventHandler += new SecondWindowEvent(secondWindow_myEventHandler);
            secondWindow.Show();
        }

        protected void secondWindow_myEventHandler(object sender, FirstWindowEventArgs e)
        {
            rtf1.AppendText(String.Format(e.Tekst));
        }

        public void btnClearText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rtf1.Text = " ";
        }
    }
```

---

Clarification from comments

I would like the Form to Change the color on close after the button is clicked. This is what I tried:

```
private void btnRed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Color c = Color.Red; 
    string s = c.ToString(); 
    this.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Are you  wanting to keep both forms open or does the Form Changing the color close after the button is clicked

Comment: the Form Changing the color close after the button is clicked. This is what i tried: private void btnRed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {Color c = Color.Red;
            string s = c.ToString();
            this.Close(); }

Comment: Can you please post some code. This will help us to know how you are opening the forms, to answer you better.

Comment: The code is posted now.

Comment: where is the declaration for `FirstWindowEventArgs` and `ColorWindowEventArgs`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, create a property on your Color Form that is set by your button you can then read it after the Form is closed when it returns from your `ShowDialog` statement.

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        if(frm2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           //this.BackColor=frm2.getColor;  helps if I read the question more closely
           richTextBox1.SelectionColor = frm2.getColor;
        }
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Color getColor { get; set; }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getColor = Color.Red;
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

---

After playing with the code that you posted and added some missing handlers, it looks like the text of your color is coming in the Format of `Color [Red]` ColorFromName has no idea how to parse that so you will need to get the actual color name by using `String.Split` Something like this.

```
protected void ColorWindow_myEventHandler(object sender, SecondWindowEventArgs e)
{
    rtf2.ForeColor = Color.FromName(e.S.Split(new string[]{"[","]"},StringSplitOptions.None)[1]);
}
```

I also noticed that you are setting your `rtf2.ForeColor` everytime that your text changes, I removed it and am now able to change the ForeColor of the RichText box.  I would be a lot easier/cleaner IMHO if you just passed the actual Color Object instead of changing it to a string and back.

This is the modified TextChanged Method note the commented out rtf2.ForeColor statement it does not belong there.

```
private void rtf2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myEventHandler != null)
    {
     myEventHandler(this, new FirstWindowEventArgs(rtf2.Text.Substring(rtf2.Text.Length -1)));
    // rtf2.ForeColor = Color.FromName(e.ToString());

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it doesn't work. I want to change the color of a text in a RichTextBox in a form when i click on a button (to fire a color event) in another form. I posted the whole code. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: How to pass Color as a Color object?

Comment: Sorry but it dosen't work for me. I used your method ColorWindow_myEventHandler and i still can't change the text color in RTB. You posted that you added some missing handlers, can you explain/post these?

Comment: Your example wouldn't compile because you were missing the EventHandlers that I asked for as a comment to your question so I had to improvise.